# cant change text value in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have 3 elements; suburb, postcode, state:

```
<div class="field">
<input class="input-text round-border" type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" size="40" validate="required:true" value="<?=$_POST['suburb']?>" /><br />
<label class="error" for="suburb">This field is required</label>
</div>

<label for="postCode" class="mandatory <?=$errors['postCode']?>">Postcode:</label>
<div class="field"><input class="input-text round-border" type="text" name="postCode" id="postCode" size="20" validate="required:true" value="<?=$_POST['postCode']?>" /><br />
<label class="error" for="postCode">This field is required</label> </div>
```

I'm using jquery autocomplete to successfully display a list of options in the suburb field:

[image]

You can see its split by comma, so I am then splitting those values up and putting them in their respective fields - ie, "VIC" goes to state field, "3088" goes to postcode - these work as you can see below, but also as you can see, I cannot get the suburb to set correctly:

[image]

So the code in the 'select' of the jquery is ( i wont put the whole thing in for sake of brevity):

```
messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function() {}
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $subpost = ui.item.value.split(", ");

            $("#postCode").val($subpost[2]);
            $("#state").val($subpost[1]);
            $("#suburb").val($subpost[0]);

            //alert('suburb = ' + $subpost[0]);
        }
```

So the code is the same for all 3 fields, but for some reason the suburb itself just wont change. 
You can also see the //alert function which correctly displays the suburb by itself but it just wont set in the field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the `select` event runs before the autocomplete actually sets the value of the `input`, so when your event handler sets the value, it's almost immediately overwritten.

What you can do is use `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0` to move your code to the end of the execution queue, so that the rest of the jQuery autocomplete code runs to completion before you attempt to set the value:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $subpost = ui.item.value.split(", ");

        $("#postCode").val($subpost[2]);
        $("#state").val($subpost[1]);
        $("#suburb").val($subpost[0]);
    }, 0);
}
```

Using `setTimeout` with a 0 timeout is a fairly common approach to queuing code up in this fashion.